# How to rollback a unreleased transport request?

Tags: abap

I have made some changes in SAP that I want to rollback.  I have not released the request yet.  How do I rollback my changes?

Do I have to release them and then reactivate an earlier version?

Or is there a way to "rollback" the current request?

I basically want to undo all of the unreleased changes I have made so far.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

- undo all changes manually (for some object types assisted by using the versioning system)
- transport the changed objects back from a system that holds the previous versions

Keep in mind that a transport request/order only records which object was changed, not what was changed inside that object.

Comment: For the first option, do I have to release the objects first?  So release the objects then try to go into the versioning history and activate an earlier version?

Comment: No. But you will have to release the transport later on to get rid of the object locks.

Answer (score 1):

SAP has version control like other development tools so the best way is to revert to the previous version of each object in version control and then delete the transport request.

If you release the transport request it creates a record of the request and depending on your companies policy it might need to be accounted for and documented.

Later.........